# How to convert .wim to .tib files?

Tags: acronis-trueimage, wim

I have a PXE server using Acronis Snap Deploy 5.
Each time I get a new version of an image from my associate, it comes as a .wim (or .iso) file.
So, to use it with ASD5, I first install it on a drive and boot up the Acronis agent to save it as a .tib file.

What I'd like to know, is if there an option to convert the .wim (and/or .iso) file directly to .tib from my local machine, so I could skip the extra step of installing it on a drive first.

Comment: Acronis does not provide a SDK to create your own *.tib Files

Comment: Acronis 2012 Software use to have the ability to convert .wim to .tib

Comment: @Moab Which "Acronis 2012" are you talking about? I mean, what is its full name (i.e. True image, server backup etc.)

Comment: @Ramhound So Moab is wrong? If not, then what do you mean by that?

Comment: Home edition, I could be wrong, I know it allowed converting Tib to Wim for sure.

Comment: @Moab Yeah well, tib to win doesn't really matter in that case. Neither Acronis and Google are really giving any helpful info in that regard.

Comment: I was wrong my version can only convert VHD to Tib

Comment: Acronis True Image 2012 is also paid software not an SDK. It also isn’t currently sold.